# Running subprocess using threadpoolexecutor

Tags: python, multithreading

How to run a subprocess with error handling lambda retry in a parallel thread using threadpoolexecutor

I want to run parallel cloning/ downloading of two repositories. While one is maintained on a custom url, the other is a git repo so makes sense to clone it directly.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
  executor.submit(download_function, url)

  retry(
        lambda: subprocess.run(["git", "clone", repository_url, path to clone to], check=True)
       )
```

I would like to run this part in parallel too

```
  retry(
        lambda: subprocess.run(["git", "clone", repository_url, path to clone to], check=True)
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

So I created a function and called subprocess from within. Pretty basic

```
def myfunc(self):
   retry(
        lambda: subprocess.run(["git", "clone", repository_url, path to clone to], check=True)
       )
```